# Integer nonlinear optimization with a fixed domain (reedited)

Tags: python, r, optimization

Here is the original table:

```
       Column1   Column2
Row1    4 (x1)    6(x3)
Row2    5 (x2)    4(x4)
```

`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` mean the new values after swapping

Originally the variance of each column is:

```
Var(column1)= var(c(4,5))=0.5
Var(column2)= var(c(6,4))=2
```

After swapping the values lesser than 10 in the original table, the new variances of two columns respectively are:

```
New_Var(column1)=(x1-(x1+x2)/2)^2+(x2-(x1+x2)/2)^2
New_Var(column2)=(x3-(x3+x4)/2)^2+(x4-(x3+x4)/2)^2
```

My objective is to

```
Minimize  | New_Var(column1) – 0.5 | + | New_Var(column2) – 2 |
```

Here the notation ‘| |’ means absolute.

The constrains are that `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` can only get a value respectively from a fixed domain, here say `{4, 5, 4, 6}`. And all the four variables need be swapped to a different value, say that `x1` cannot be 4, `x3` cannot be 6 so on so forth.

Note that all values in the original table here are larger than 10 because I just want to make the question look like simple.

In realistic, the table is `6000*10` which is very large. So outputting all the unique permutations and testing  is not a suitable method.

I have read the `task view of optimization` in R. There are a lot of optimization packages there. So I need more specific guidance.

Below is the function that can swap values lesser than 10 to a different values lesser than 10 respectively. Hope it helps.

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(all(y != x)) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}

set.seed(10)
swapFun(c(1,2,3,10,4,11,2,12))
#[1]  2  4 10  2 11  1 12
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want to permute the values in the table so that the variance of each column doesn't change? Why would you want to do that? Can you tell me what the domain size is?

Comment: Hi, I just give a simple example here. Sometimes I want to minimize the difference of the mean of each column, the difference of correlations between columns. So I need a suitable optimization package. The domain only contains numbers in `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. If the number of variables is 20, then the length of the domain is 20 which means there are some repeated numbers in the domain. For example, the domain now maybe`1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6`.